# How to install package from github repo in Yarn

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

When I use `npm install fancyapps/fancybox#v2.6.1 --save`, so fancybox package at v2.6.1 tag will be installed. This behavior is described in [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)

I want to ask, how to do this with `yarn`?

Is this command the right alternative? In [yarn docs](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/add/) isn't anything about this format.

```
yarn add fancyapps/fancybox#v2.6.1
```

Answer (score 358, accepted):

You can add any Git repository (or tarball) as a dependency to `yarn` by specifying the remote URL (either HTTPS or SSH):

```
yarn add <git remote url> installs a package from a remote git repository.
yarn add <git remote url>#<branch/commit/tag> installs a package from a remote git repository at specific git branch, git commit or git tag.
yarn add https://my-project.org/package.tgz installs a package from a remote gzipped tarball.
```

Here are some examples:

```
yarn add https://github.com/fancyapps/fancybox [remote url]
yarn add ssh://github.com/fancyapps/fancybox#3.0  [branch]
yarn add https://github.com/fancyapps/fancybox#5cda5b529ce3fb6c167a55d42ee5a316e921d95f [commit]
```

*(Note: Fancybox v2.6.1 isn't available in the Git version.)*

To support both npm and yarn, you can use the git+url syntax:

```sh
git+https://github.com/owner/package.git#commithashortagorbranch
git+ssh://github.com/owner/package.git#commithashortagorbranch
```

Comment: but can not use git@xxx style

Comment: If the SSH option was added to this answer we could probably lose all of the others.

Comment: Don't forget you can use semantic versioning!
`yarn add https://github.com/fancyapps/fancybox.git#semver:^3.0`
This will pull the latest major version, which is currently 3.5.7.

Comment: Adding a dist folder might be needed as well for resolving the module.

Comment: For SSH with private repository, i found we need to add user `git`. e.g: `yarn add ssh://git@github.com/fancyapps/fancybox#3.0`

Comment: Is there a way to do that in package.json?

Comment: This doesn't work in Yarn 2; you need to add `my-package-name@` in front of the url. See here: https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/issues/994#issuecomment-591853492

Comment: @oligopol is there any way not to have dist folder on github and still be able to use git repo as a dependency? Like building after yarn downloads the files

Comment: I have tried the sample above but I'm getting the following error message: `error Can't add "<component-name>": invalid package version "1.0"` My package is found in my company's GitLab and the version in package.json is 1.0.   Does the version need to be three digits?

Answer (score 61):

### Yarn 2+

Installing from remote URLs has changed slightly with [Yarn 2](https://yarnpkg.com/). Specifically, [remote URLs must be prefixed with the package name](https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/issues/994#issuecomment-628586986). So for github this means:

```
yarn add '<package name>@https://github.com/<github user>/<github repo>'
```

Make sure that `<package name>` matches the value in the `"name"` field of the repo's `package.json` file.

To target a specific branch add either `head=<branch>` or `commit=<full commit hash>` via the URL fragment:

```
yarn add '<package name>@https://github.com/<github user>/<github repo>#head=<branch name>'
```

If you're trying to install an individual package from a Yarn monorepo on github you can add `workspace=<package name>` to the URL fragment:

```
yarn add '<package name>@https://github.com/<github user>/<github repo>#head=<branch name>&workspace=<package name>'
```

Comment: how to install from PR?

Comment: @CodeBy replace <github user>/<github repo>#head=<branch name> with the source user/repo/branch of the PR

Comment: <package name> will name the package <package name> with those <> you should remove it. it is not within the syntax

Comment: Where did you find the docs `workspacke=<workspace>`?

Answer (score 35):

For ssh style urls just add ssh before the url:

```
yarn add ssh://<whatever>@<xxx>#<branch,tag,commit>
```

Comment: This worked for me when `yarn` refused to honor the common `git` ssh url syntax: Did work: `yarn add ssh://git@github.com:my-org/my-repo#commit_hash`
Did not work: `yarn add git@github.com:my-org/my-repo#commit_hash`

Comment: Is there a way to do that but from package.json with yarn install?

Answer (score 21):

This is described here: https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add#toc-adding-dependencies

For example:

```
yarn add https://github.com/novnc/noVNC.git#0613d18
```

Answer (score 15):

For *GitHub* (or similar) private repository:

```
yarn add 'ssh://git@github.com:myproject.git#<branch,tag,commit>'
npm install 'ssh://git@github.com:myproject.git#<branch,tag,commit>'
```

Answer (score 11):

I use this short format for github repositories:

`yarn add github_user/repository_name#commit_hash`

Answer (score 3):

With the latest version of Yarn, they require a package name before the URL. If you're installing a private package that you published to Github Packages, the syntax is like this:

`yarn add @organization/packagename@https://github.com/organization/packagename`,

Which should yield this line in package.json:

`"@organization/packagename": "https://github.com/organization/packagename"`