# How to use 'yarn install' to install a package that is hosted on our Bitbucket Cloud repository from within Microsoft Hosted Azure Pipeline

Tags: git, ssh, azure-devops, yarnpkg

We use Azure DevOps Pipelines and have a pipeline using Microsoft hosted agent.

There is a step we need in our build pipeline that runs 'yarn install' to fetch a repo hosted on our Bitbucket Cloud private repository.

We have tried:

- persistCredentials: true
- Dynamically editing the URL in the package.json file from within the Pipeline to https://:@bitbucket.org/... (where  is a secure variable) [but this seems to be written as '***'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miRqw.png)
- InstallSSHKey@0 task to then use ssh instead of https to fetch, but [this also fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jllVp.jpg).

We are expecting yarn install to be able to authenticate with our private Bitbucket cloud repo and pull the package/repo.

Comment: How does the value being used in the `package.json` file looks like? `"dependencies": { 
 "package-name": "git+https://<user>:<password>@<url-repository>.git" }` or `git+ssh://...` should also work

Comment: @Jhilton it is: "package-name": "https://<url-repository>.git"

I am also trying to do some testing with ssh://git@...

We are open to using either. We currently have a task that will modify that line in the pipeline to match https/ssh depending on what we choose to use.

However currently changing https://repo.com/org/reponame.git to ssh://git@repo.com/org/reponame.git causes "Invalid package.json in package.json" error. So I am also troubleshooting that at the moment.

Is git+XXXXX required?

Comment: Yes, the `git+` syntax is  supported both in npm and yarn. Maybe you can check this other answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43411864/how-to-install-package-from-github-repo-in-yarn

Answer (score 0):

For future reference I ended up doing 'yarn remove ' and 'yarn add' with some regex to massage the URL into the ssh format.

The InstallSSHKey@0 task is now working - just had to add values for every single parameter (including the non-optional ones).