# Trying to get a branch of a github repo into my code. Even though I'm using what I'm pretty sure is correct in package.json, it runs master instead

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg, package.json

I'm trying to get a certain branch that I'm working on on a repo into my code to use as a library, but even though its linked correctly, its still using master. This is the current line that should be getting the branch from the repo. `"@dustup/react-tournament-brackets": "dustup-gg/react-tournament-brackets#jake",`

I've had a look in the node_modules folder, and the code from the correct branch is in there, however it's just when it starts to run that it uses master despite that. I've tried other branches as well, and no matter what it always uses the code in master. Just to check there's been console.logs in both branches and only the ones in master are shown.

Full package.json file :

```
{
  "name": "tournament-brackets",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@dustup/react-tournament-brackets": "dustup-gg/react-tournament-brackets#jake",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^4.1.3",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0",
    "yarn": "^1.22.19"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't look like [git reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43411864/1048572) at all